CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE very slow on MariaDB 10.11.6
I have MariaDB 10.11.6 installed on my Synology RS822 w/ 8GB RAM, and I've found that CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE are very slow. Even calling DROP TABLE IF EXISTS on a nonexistent table takes well over 1000ms, with the bulk of the time consumed by the 'closing tables' phase:
SET profiling = 1; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo; SHOW PROFILE;
+------------------------+----------+
| Status                 | Duration |
+------------------------+----------+
| Starting               | 0.000022 |
| checking permissions   | 0.000021 |
| Opening tables         | 0.000020 |
| After opening tables   | 0.000004 |
| System lock            | 0.000004 |
| table lock             | 0.000024 |
| Unlocking tables       | 0.000005 |
| closing tables         | 1.355043 |
| Query end              | 0.000011 |
| Commit                 | 0.000004 |
| closing tables         | 0.000003 |
| Commit implicit        | 0.000009 |
| Starting cleanup       | 0.000003 |
| Freeing items          | 0.000006 |
| Updating status        | 0.000035 |
| Reset for next command | 0.000018 |
+------------------------+----------+

When creating a table, the majority of the time is instead spent in "creating table" and "After create". Existing/established databases seem to have normal performance with respect to SELECT, INSERT, etc. I've tried various settings for innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit, innodb_flush_method, and innodb_buffer_pool_size, with no effect.
This database is stored on a volume formatted with btrfs, and I've read that it is not recommended to run MariaDB on btrfs filesystems. Would this alone account for this performance problem? Is there anything I could do to mitigate it?
Edit: Here's the strace output monitoring mariadbd as the client connects and DROP TABLE is issued (lines 0056 through 0222 are probably most relevant).
0001 [pid  3257]      0.000032 accept4(69, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(51994), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.39")}, [128 => 16], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 94
0002 [pid  3257]      0.000111 futex(0x55df95f8a84c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
0003 [pid 21842]      0.000045 <... restart_syscall resumed>) = 0
0004 [pid  3257]      0.000016 <... futex resumed>) = 1
0005 [pid 21842]      0.000015 futex(0x55df95f8a890, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
0006 [pid  3257]      0.000017 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0007 [pid 21842]      0.000018 <... futex resumed>) = 0
0008 [pid  3257]      0.000017 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0009 [pid 21842]      0.000018 gettid( <unfinished ...>
0010 [pid  3257]      0.000014 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0011 [pid 21842]      0.000016 <... gettid resumed>) = 21842
0012 [pid  3257]      0.000011 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0013 [pid  3257]      0.000027 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0014 [pid 21842]      0.000018 fcntl(94, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK <unfinished ...>
0015 [pid  3257]      0.000014 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0016 [pid 21842]      0.000013 <... fcntl resumed>) = 0
0017 [pid  3257]      0.000009 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0018 [pid 21842]      0.000014 setsockopt(94, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4 <unfinished ...>
0019 [pid  3257]      0.000018 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0020 [pid 21842]      0.000014 <... setsockopt resumed>) = 0
0021 [pid  3257]      0.000011 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0022 [pid 21842]      0.000015 setsockopt(94, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4 <unfinished ...>
0023 [pid  3257]      0.000017 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0024 [pid 21842]      0.000013 <... setsockopt resumed>) = 0
0025 [pid  3257]      0.000010 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0026 [pid 21842]      0.000015 gettid( <unfinished ...>
0027 [pid  3257]      0.000012 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0028 [pid 21842]      0.000013 <... gettid resumed>) = 21842
0029 [pid  3257]      0.000010 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0030 [pid 21842]      0.000015 gettid( <unfinished ...>
0031 [pid  3257]      0.000012 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0032 [pid 21842]      0.000012 <... gettid resumed>) = 21842
0033 [pid  3257]      0.000010 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0034 [pid 21842]      0.000016 getpeername(94,  <unfinished ...>
0035 [pid  3257]      0.000014 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0036 [pid 21842]      0.000013 <... getpeername resumed>{sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(51994), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.39")}, [128 => 16]) = 0
0037 [pid  3257]      0.000018 accept4(69,  <unfinished ...>
0038 [pid 21842]      0.000016 setsockopt(94, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4 <unfinished ...>
0039 [pid  3257]      0.000029 <... accept4 resumed>0x7ffc1d9bfcd0, [128], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0040 [pid 21842]      0.000013 <... setsockopt resumed>) = 0
0041 [pid  3257]      0.000010 poll([{fd=69, events=POLLIN}, {fd=70, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1 <unfinished ...>
0042 [pid 21842]      0.000021 sendto(94, "Y\0\0\0\n5.5.5-10.11.6-MariaDB\0\177\2\0\0j"..., 93, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 93
0043 [pid 21842]      0.000081 recvfrom(94, 0x7f40540128f8, 4, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0044 [pid 21842]      0.000036 poll([{fd=94, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 10000) = 1 ([{fd=94, revents=POLLIN}])
0045 [pid 21842]      0.013485 recvfrom(94, "\331\0\0\1", 4, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 4
0046 [pid 21842]      0.000076 recvfrom(94, "\214\242\277\0\0\0\0\1!\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\35\0\0\0"..., 217, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 217
0047 [pid 21842]      0.000113 sendto(94, "\25\0\0\2\0\0\0\2@\0\0\0\f\1\n\tnextcloud", 25, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 25
0048 [pid 21842]      0.000071 recvfrom(94, 0x7f40540128f8, 4, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0049 [pid 21842]      0.000039 poll([{fd=94, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 28800000) = 1 ([{fd=94, revents=POLLIN}])
0050 [pid 21842]      0.005863 recvfrom(94, "\22\0\0\0", 4, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 4
0051 [pid 21842]      0.000066 recvfrom(94, "\3SET profiling = 1", 18, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 18
0052 [pid 21842]      0.000148 sendto(94, "\7\0\0\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0", 11, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 11
0053 [pid 21842]      0.000079 recvfrom(94, 0x7f40540128f8, 4, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0054 [pid 21842]      0.000039 poll([{fd=94, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 28800000) = 1 ([{fd=94, revents=POLLIN}])
0055 [pid 21842]      0.005712 recvfrom(94, "\31\0\0\0", 4, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 4
0056 [pid 21842]      0.000063 recvfrom(94, "\3DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo", 25, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 25
0057 [pid 21842]      0.000054 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=874000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=238000}, ...}) = 0
0058 [pid 21842]      0.000080 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=238000}, ...}) = 0
0059 [pid 21842]      0.000070 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=238000}, ...}) = 0
0060 [pid 21842]      0.000057 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=238000}, ...}) = 0
0061 [pid 21842]      0.000038 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=238000}, ...}) = 0
0062 [pid 21842]      0.000037 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=238000}, ...}) = 0
0063 [pid 21842]      0.000059 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=238000}, ...}) = 0
0064 [pid 21842]      0.000043 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=238000}, ...}) = 0
0065 [pid 21842]      0.000050 openat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.frm", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0066 [pid 21842]      0.000064 pwrite64(3, "\2\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096, 4096) = 4096
0067 [pid 21842]      0.000059 fdatasync(3 <unfinished ...>
0068 [pid  3259]      0.048012 <... futex resumed>) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
0069 [pid  3259]      0.000060 futex(0x55df9684d760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
0070 [pid  3259]      0.000076 futex(0x55df9684d74c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1720136967, tv_nsec=51411000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0071 [pid 21842]      0.181468 <... fdatasync resumed>) = 0
0072 [pid 21842]      0.000034 pwrite64(3, "\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096, 8192) = 4096
0073 [pid 21842]      0.000073 fdatasync(3 <unfinished ...>
0074 [pid  3259]      0.013488 <... futex resumed>) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
0075 [pid  3259]      0.000042 futex(0x55df97d88c28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
0076 [pid 21571]      0.000039 <... futex resumed>) = 0
0077 [pid  3259]      0.000009 futex(0x55df9684d760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
0078 [pid 21571]      0.000013 futex(0x55df97d88760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
0079 [pid  3259]      0.000012 <... futex resumed>) = 0
0080 [pid 21571]      0.000010 <... futex resumed>) = 0
0081 [pid  3259]      0.000010 futex(0x55df9684d74c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1720136967, tv_nsec=256342000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0082 [pid 21571]      0.000025 futex(0x55df97d88c2c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=1387274, tv_nsec=722924820}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0083 [pid  3259]      0.204788 <... futex resumed>) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
0084 [pid  3259]      0.000049 futex(0x55df9684d760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
0085 [pid  3259]      0.000054 futex(0x55df9684d74c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1720136967, tv_nsec=656493000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0086 [pid 21842]      0.161208 <... fdatasync resumed>) = 0
0087 [pid 21842]      0.000048 pwrite64(3, "\2\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096, 12288) = 4096
0088 [pid 21842]      0.000077 fdatasync(3)  = 0
0089 [pid 21842]      0.058199 pwrite64(3, "\3\0\0\0", 4, 4100) = 4
0090 [pid 21842]      0.000084 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0091 [pid 21842]      0.000048 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40475b0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0092 [pid 21842]      0.000055 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0093 [pid 21842]      0.000054 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0094 [pid 21842]      0.000102 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.ARZ", 0x7f40d4048df0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0095 [pid 21842]      0.000044 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.ARZ") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0096 [pid 21842]      0.000046 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0097 [pid 21842]      0.000038 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40475b0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0098 [pid 21842]      0.000042 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0099 [pid 21842]      0.000038 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0100 [pid 21842]      0.000042 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.ARM", 0x7f40d4048df0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0101 [pid 21842]      0.000045 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.ARM") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0102 [pid 21842]      0.000082 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0103 [pid 21842]      0.000044 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40453d0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0104 [pid 21842]      0.000046 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/foo.MAI", 0x7f40d40453d0, 1023) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0105 [pid 21842]      0.000050 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0106 [pid 21842]      0.000039 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d4047540, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0107 [pid 21842]      0.000044 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0108 [pid 21842]      0.000040 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0109 [pid 21842]      0.000045 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.MAI", 0x7f40d4048d80, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0110 [pid 21842]      0.000042 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.MAI") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0111 [pid 21842]      0.000051 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0112 [pid 21842]      0.000037 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d4047540, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0113 [pid 21842]      0.000042 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0114 [pid 21842]      0.000038 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0115 [pid 21842]      0.000043 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.MAD", 0x7f40d4048d80, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0116 [pid 21842]      0.000041 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.MAD") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0117 [pid 21842]      0.000044 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0118 [pid 21842]      0.000036 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d4047540, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0119 [pid 21842]      0.000054 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0120 [pid 21842]      0.000053 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0121 [pid 21842]      0.000041 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.TMD", 0x7f40d4048d80, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0122 [pid 21842]      0.000040 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.TMD") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0123 [pid 21842]      0.000050 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0124 [pid 21842]      0.000040 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40475b0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0125 [pid 21842]      0.000045 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0126 [pid 21842]      0.000039 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0127 [pid 21842]      0.000046 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.MRG", 0x7f40d4048df0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0128 [pid 21842]      0.000042 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.MRG") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0129 [pid 21842]      0.000048 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0130 [pid 21842]      0.000038 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40477f0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0131 [pid 21842]      0.000043 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0132 [pid 21842]      0.000042 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0133 [pid 21842]      0.000047 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.MYI", 0x7f40d4049030, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0134 [pid 21842]      0.000042 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.MYI") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0135 [pid 21842]      0.000046 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0136 [pid 21842]      0.000038 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40477f0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0137 [pid 21842]      0.000044 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0138 [pid 21842]      0.000040 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0139 [pid 21842]      0.000045 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.MYD", 0x7f40d4049030, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0140 [pid 21842]      0.000042 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.MYD") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0141 [pid 21842]      0.000046 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0142 [pid 21842]      0.000037 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40477f0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0143 [pid 21842]      0.000042 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0144 [pid 21842]      0.000040 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0145 [pid 21842]      0.000057 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.OLD", 0x7f40d4049030, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0146 [pid 21842]      0.000049 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.OLD") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0147 [pid 21842]      0.000043 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0148 [pid 21842]      0.000038 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40477f0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0149 [pid 21842]      0.000044 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0150 [pid 21842]      0.000039 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0151 [pid 21842]      0.000056 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.TMD", 0x7f40d4049030, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0152 [pid 21842]      0.000042 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.TMD") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0153 [pid 21842]      0.000046 openat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.par", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0154 [pid 21842]      0.000054 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0155 [pid 21842]      0.000036 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40475b0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0156 [pid 21842]      0.000042 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0157 [pid 21842]      0.000038 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0158 [pid 21842]      0.000042 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.CSV", 0x7f40d4048df0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0159 [pid 21842]      0.000040 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.CSV") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0160 [pid 21842]      0.000041 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0161 [pid 21842]      0.000037 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40475b0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0162 [pid 21842]      0.000038 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0163 [pid 21842]      0.000035 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0164 [pid 21842]      0.000038 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.CSM", 0x7f40d4048df0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0165 [pid 21842]      0.000037 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.CSM") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0166 [pid 21842]      0.000037 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0167 [pid 21842]      0.000035 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d40475b0, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0168 [pid 21842]      0.000038 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0169 [pid 21842]      0.000035 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0170 [pid 21842]      0.000051 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "./nextcloud/foo.CSN", 0x7f40d4048df0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0171 [pid 21842]      0.000039 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.CSN") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0172 [pid 21842]      0.000067 getcwd("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10", 1024) = 38
0173 [pid 21842]      0.000035 readlink("/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud", 0x7f40d4048530, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
0174 [pid 21842]      0.000061 faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
0175 [pid 21842]      0.000037 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/volume1/@appdata/MariaDB10/mariadb10/nextcloud/", F_OK) = 0
0176 [pid 21842]      0.000041 unlink("./nextcloud/foo.frm") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0177 [pid 21842]      0.000040 pwrite64(3, "\1", 1, 12290) = 1
0178 [pid 21842]      0.000058 fdatasync(3 <unfinished ...>
0179 [pid  3259]      0.176464 <... futex resumed>) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
0180 [pid  3259]      0.000049 futex(0x55df9684d760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
0181 [pid  3259]      0.000061 futex(0x55df9684d74c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1720136968, tv_nsec=51651000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0182 [pid 21842]      0.073126 <... fdatasync resumed>) = 0
0183 [pid 21842]      0.000042 access("./nextcloud/foo.TRG", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
0184 [pid 21842]      0.000082 pwrite64(3, "\2", 1, 12290) = 1
0185 [pid 21842]      0.000087 fdatasync(3)  = 0
0186 [pid 21842]      0.083138 pwrite64(3, "\3", 1, 8192) = 1
0187 [pid 21842]      0.000080 fdatasync(3 <unfinished ...>
0188 [pid  3259]      0.238536 <... futex resumed>) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
0189 [pid  3259]      0.000062 futex(0x55df97d88c2c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
0190 [pid 21571]      0.000051 <... futex resumed>) = 0
0191 [pid  3259]      0.000011 <... futex resumed>) = 1
0192 [pid 21571]      0.000009 futex(0x55df97d88760, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
0193 [pid  3259]      0.000012 futex(0x55df97d88760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
0194 [pid 21571]      0.000017 <... futex resumed>) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0195 [pid  3259]      0.000013 <... futex resumed>) = 0
0196 [pid 21571]      0.000015 futex(0x55df97d88760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
0197 [pid  3259]      0.000008 futex(0x55df9684d760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
0198 [pid 21571]      0.000010 <... futex resumed>) = 0
0199 [pid  3259]      0.000008 <... futex resumed>) = 0
0200 [pid  3259]      0.000024 futex(0x55df9684d74c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1720136968, tv_nsec=56638000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0201 [pid 21571]      0.000033 futex(0x55df97d88c28, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=1387275, tv_nsec=723323415}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0202 [pid  3259]      0.004623 <... futex resumed>) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
0203 [pid  3259]      0.000027 futex(0x55df9684d760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
0204 [pid  3259]      0.000044 futex(0x55df9684d74c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1720136968, tv_nsec=456727000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0205 [pid 21842]      0.048187 <... fdatasync resumed>) = 0
0206 [pid 21842]      0.000049 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=253000}, ...}) = 0
0207 [pid 21842]      0.000058 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=253000}, ...}) = 0
0208 [pid 21842]      0.000036 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=253000}, ...}) = 0
0209 [pid 21842]      0.000036 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=253000}, ...}) = 0
0210 [pid 21842]      0.000043 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=253000}, ...}) = 0
0211 [pid 21842]      0.000036 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=253000}, ...}) = 0
0212 [pid 21842]      0.000037 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=253000}, ...}) = 0
0213 [pid 21842]      0.000036 sendto(94, "\7\0\0\1\0\0\0\2\0\1\0", 11, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 11
0214 [pid 21842]      0.000075 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=254000}, ...}) = 0
0215 [pid 21842]      0.000056 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=10, tv_usec=875000}, ru_stime={tv_sec=2, tv_usec=254000}, ...}) = 0
0216 [pid 21842]      0.000038 recvfrom(94, 0x7f40540128f8, 4, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
0217 [pid 21842]      0.000047 poll([{fd=94, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 28800000 <unfinished ...>
0218 [pid  3259]      0.351345 <... futex resumed>) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
0219 [pid  3259]      0.000053 futex(0x55df9684d760, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
0220 [pid  3259]      0.000053 futex(0x55df9684d74c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1720136968, tv_nsec=856906000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
0221 [pid 21842]      0.394824 <... poll resumed>) = 1 ([{fd=94, revents=POLLIN}])
0222 [pid 21842]      0.000202 recvfrom(94, "\r\0\0\0", 4, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 4 


Can you strace  --relative-timestamps -f  -p  $(pidof mariadbd) and perform the drop table and see the relative time on elements. Include this in your question by editing it.

I've added the strace output. It seems that many futex() calls are returning ETIMEDOUT, but I'm not sure what to make of that.

The 3 initial fdatasyncs are around Atomic DDL for the crash safety. I'm unsure what the mutex time represents.

"are very slow" -- compared to what?  If you are comparing to pre-10.6, then Dan's comment is the answer.

The CREATE TABLE operations are slow enough to cause the Nextcloud installer to time-out and fail. Nextcloud needs to create a few dozen tables during setup, and this would take minutes at the speeds I was observing. All local on the same host.
